# Question about autorelease object in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I have an instance variable called `users` defined as `NSMutableArray`.

I use that variable for fill an `UITableView`.

In `viewDidLoad` I initialize it with:

```
users = [[MySingleton sharedClass] getUsers];
```

This is the `getUsers` method:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getUsers
{
    ...   
    NSMutableArray *listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonObject) {
        ...
        [listArray addObject:element];
        ...
    }

    return listArray;
}
```

In this way all it works fine. The problem is when I set listArray as autoreleased object.

```
NSMutableArray *listArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
return [listArray autorelease];
```

Sometimes the app crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Why this? Isn't correct set `autorelease` listArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `users` in `users = [[MySingleton sharedClass] getUsers]` is an instance variable, you're forgetting to take ownership of the array. When you want to claim ownership of an object (such as this array), you need to send it `retain` to tell it you want it to stick around. And when you're finished with it, you need to send it `release` to tell it so. Setters handle this for you, so it's generally a good idea to use setters outside of init and dealloc methods. So assuming you have a setter for `users`, you could do one of these:

```
self.users = [[MySingleton sharedClass] getUsers];
/* OR */
users = [[[MySingleton sharedClass] getUsers] retain];
```

The first way is usually better, but you don't want to call setters in `init…` or `dealloc` methods because they might have side effects that are undesirable there. Since you're not in one of those methods here, you can just use the first.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But what's the difference of `self.users = ...` and `users = ...`? Also, should I set listArray as autorelease in `getUsers` method, correct?

Comment: @Fred Collins: Yes, that method should autorelease the array. And the difference between `users =` and `self.users =` is that one sets an instance variable and the other calls a property setter.

Answer (score 0):

You have created and assigned an autoreleased object to user. By specifying autorelease you are saying that system could free it. So when it reaches the end of autorelease pool its removed from memory. That is why when you try to access it late it crashes. So if you need it to be global then you need to retain it.